Python Selenium stuck on webdriver.Chrome(), doesn't run further lines of code and doesn't give any errors in the terminal
I have a python project, which mostly uses Selenium. On my machine everything works fine, but when I send the code to the colleague, the browser opens, but it stays on "data;" and doesn't open anything else. The terminal doesn't give any errors, just a note, that DevTools listening on ...
I tried creating a sample program to narrow down what causes the problem, and it seems, that it's the webdriver.Chrome() line of code, which was last to run, anything else just waiting for something.
Chromedriver installed in the right path, as well as in PATH var. Tested with 126 and 127 Chrome versions, same issue.
If I remove the chromedriver from the path, it says, that program can't find it, so initially the program knows where it is located.
Does anyone know what can be the problem?
Python 3.9.0
Selenium 4.8.0
Win 10
Chromedriver and Chrome: 126/127 (same issue for both)
